# PFFile to UIImage

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimage

Hi I know there are already questions about this subject however I can't get my code to work. I'm in xcode 7.2 beta using swift 2.

I want the Image to be the background of my button:

```
self.Button1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: [Here the image of in the PFFFile] , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

So can someone explain me how to convert the PFFile to an UIImage useable for the background of a button?

```
 func Call(){   let countQuery = PFQuery(className: "My_Classname")
    countQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) { let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            let query = PFQuery(className: "My_Classname")
            query.skip = randomNumber; query.limit = 1
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                 if (error == nil) {
let object: AnyObject = objects![0]
self.image1 = object ["image1"] as! PFFile!
self.image2 = object ["image2"] as! PFFile!
self.image3 = object ["image3"] as! PFFile!
self.image4 = object ["image4"] as! PFFile!
```

I hope someone could help me! Most of the codes here on stackoverflow are in xcode 6 swift.

Comment: Why are you using a beta copy of Xcode 7.2? It's been public for a while now. You should update to the non-beta version.

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pffile+uiimage+%5Bswift%5D).